# look for a value from a pandas dataframe into another using an inequality condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I Have two pd.Dataframes:

```
A = [ timestamp      key 
      12-12-2012:00  AAAA
      13-12-2012:00  AAAA
    ...]
```

and a second one:

```
B = [ timestamp      key 
      12-12-2015:00  AAAA
      13-12-2012:00  BBBB
      ...]
```

I want to search if for each row in `A` is there a row in `B` (with the same key) where the date is in `(B.timestamp - pd.timedelta(x), B.timestamp)`. In `SQL` you can make a `left join` using:

```
ON (A.key = B.key) AND (A.timestamp >= B.timestamp - pd.timedelta(x)) AND (A.timestamp <= B.timestamp)
```

Is there a way to get the same result in `pandas`?

pd. my solution so far is to replicate/append B dataframe n-times, for each date until `B.timestamp - pd.timedelta(x)`. Considering all `A.timestamp` and then apply `pd.merge` but it must be a more "pythonic" way to get the result

Comment: a date range, for example `AAAA`, `date` is in `A` i need to search in `B` if the `AAAA` key apears with `date` between `date` and `date+somedays`

Answer (score 0):

You can use where for this, I am using a simple example you can replicate the same with your data:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"])
a["A"]=[1,2,3]
a["B"]=[11,22,33]

print(a.where((a.A > 1) & (a.A <=3)).dropna())
```

The output will be :

```
    A   B
1   2.0 22.0
2   3.0 33.0
```

Note: you can use any value at the place of 1 or 3 in the above code

Comment: but I need that the "timestamp" is in a range, not only in an equality.